# android 2.3 MediaPlayer MPEG AAC Audio

Tags: android, media-player, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to play an audio recorded from iPhone in android. The following are the source code the playing the video in android. The extension of the file is MP4.

```
Uri savedUri = Uri.fromFile(savedUri_file);     
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, getImageUri());
mediaPlayer.start();
```

The MediaPlayer.create returns a null value. In VLC I have checked the codec information of the audio. It is MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a).

I need to play this in android 2.3. In jelly bean its is working fine. Also I tried with videoview in 2.3, its working. The audio is playing.

Also when I tried play the same file from SD card (by taping on the MP4 file) its played int he default player.

But when I am trying to play the audio created from android device its playing. The codec information of the audion file created from android is AMR Narrow Band (samr).

The following are the code used for creating audio from

```
NSMutableDictionary *defaultSettings = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]autorelease];
[defaultSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[defaultSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[defaultSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
```

Any hints?

Comment: I remember that one of my  Android phones simply was unable to pay AAC  files. Even media player apps that promised to work with AAC  files wouldn't play them. Perhaps your 2.3  phone has the save restriction?

Comment: when I tried play the same file from SD card (by taping on the MP4 file) its played int he default player